# MATLAB | How to use the result from exist?

Tags: matlab

I am doing a basic MATLAB online-course and in one part of the last assignment I need to "create a line graph from an expression based on user input".

My interpretation is that a user should be able to type in an expression f(x)=... such as:

```
3x^2+3x+c
```

- I have successfully written code that will ask the user for the number of variables (numbers before the x:s) and exponents and if there is an constant or not.
- Also, my code then generates variables from user input (`input`: string -> `genvarname`), and then assigns a correct value to it also from user input via the `eval` command/function.
- Lastly, I have done an `for`-loop and used `exist` to determine if a variable exists.

My question now is, how can I use the result from `exist` (eg = 1) in a `if`-loop to access the variable and store it in an vector.

That way I believe I can with another for loop calculate values for y. the x-values are just `x = -50:1:50`, but if there are any suggestions for how to calculate y simpler than please tell me.

I have gained lots of information from reading StackOverflow posts, I just hope my question is relevant, and helpful. :)

EDIT:

```
 %% Initial questions
IN = input('Give foo: [på formen A1x^a1+A2x^a2...Nx^n+KONST] ','s');
    if isempty(IN)
        IN = '3x^2+4x+2';
    end
disp(['Du vill plotta ' IN]);
vars_qty = input('Hur många variabler har du? ');
    if isempty(vars_qty)
        vars_qty = 2;
    end
exps_qty = vars_qty;

const = input('Har du en konstant på slutet? [Ja/Nej] ','s');
    if isempty(const)
        const = 'Ja';
    end
disp(' ');
%vars_vector_name = cell(vars_qty, 1); % cell array with variable names
vars_vector_vals = zeros(vars_qty, 1); % vector with variable values
%exps_vector_name = cell(exps_qty, 1); % cell array with exponent names
exps_vector_vals = zeros(exps_qty, 1); % vector with exponent values
%% Assigning vectors
x = -50:1:50; % x vector
A = zeros(vars_qty, 1);
a = zeros(vars_qty, 1);
%% Assigning variable and exponent names + create variables and set a value to it
    for i = 1:vars_qty
        disp(['Variabel ' num2str(i) ':']);
%        vars_vector_name(i, 1) = cellstr(input('Var god och namnge variabeln [A1,B..] ', 's')); % 
            ... does not like an empty input
        var = input('Var god och namnge variabeln [A1,A2...An] ', 's');
%             if isempty(var)
%                 var = ['A',num2str(i)];
%             end
        vars_vector_vals(i, 1) = input('Vad är värdet på variabeln? '); % 
            ... does not like an empty input
%             if isempty(vars_vector_vals(i, 1))
%                 vars_vector_vals(i, 1) = i;
%             end
        vars_gen = genvarname( var );
        eval([ var '= vars_vector_vals(i, 1);' ]);
        vars_exist = exist( ['A',num2str(i)], 'var'); % isvarname( num2str(vars_gen) ); % num2str(vars_gen)
             if vars_exist == 1
                 disp('Exist!');
%                 A(i, 1) = vars_gen;
%                A(i, 1) = eval([ var '= vars_vector_vals(i, 1);' ]);
             else
                 ...
             end
        disp(['Exponent ' num2str(i) ':']);
        exps = input('Var god och namnge exponenten [a1,a2...an & a2<a1] ', 's');
%             if isempty(exps)
%                 exp = ['a',num2str(i)];
%             end
        exps_vector_vals(i, 1) = input('Vad är värdet på exponenten? '); % 
            ... does not like an empty input
%             if isempty(exps_vector_vals(i, 1))
%                 exps_vector_vals(i, 1) = i;
%             end
        exps_gen = genvarname( exps );
        eval([ exps '= exps_vector_vals(i, 1);' ]);  
        exps_exist = exist( ['a',num2str(i)], 'var'); % isvarname( num2str(exps_gen) ); % num2str(exps_gen)
             if exps_exist == 1
                 disp('Exist!');
%                 a(i, 1) = exps_gen;
%                 a(i, 1) = eval([ exps '= exps_vector_vals(i, 1);' ]);  
             else
                 ...
             end    
    end
%        exps_vector_name(j, 1) = cellstr(input('Var god och namnge exponenten [a,b.. & b<a] ', 's')); % 
            ... does not like an empty input
    if strcmp(const,'Ja')
        disp(' ');
        const_scalar = input('Vad är värdet på konstanten? '); % scalar with constant
    else
        const_scalar = 0;
    end
%gen_vars = genvarname({ (vars_vector_name(:,1)) });
%gen_exps = genvarname({ (exps_vector_name(:,1)) });
%eval([ gen_vars '= vars_vector_vals(:,1);' ]); % doesn't like a cell array
%eval([ gen_exps '= exps_vector_vals(:,1);' ]); % doesn't like a cell array
y = zeros(vars_qty, 1);
%     for k = 1:vars_qty
%         y(k, 1) = 
%     end
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far

Comment: @Dan, done, I didn't include it at first because it was rather long.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's [EXIST](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) command is a little tricky to use correctly because it checks so many things. Here's how I would write this:

```
userVarName = ...
if exist(userVarName, 'var') == 1 % Return value 1 indicates a variable.
   varValue = eval(userVarName);
else
   error('Variable "%s" does not exist.', userVarName);
end
```

*EDIT*
Looks like the relevant portion of your code needs to be adapted like so:

```
vars_name = ['A', num2str(j)];
if exist(vars_name, 'var') == 1
    A(j, 1) = eval(vars_name);
end
```

Comment: yes I have used the `var` as well, and used `eval`to give it a value, but I don't know how to access the said variable after using `exist` and determined it's there.

Comment: I have tried incorporating that into my code by inserting it in my main `for`-loop, but with no luck - I get `Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment`.

Comment: What is "A(j,1)" at the time of the problem?

Comment: It should be 1. I have updated my code up top. When I run the code as it is right now, the code works. But as soon as I comment away that `eval` line and use the one in `if`-loop I get that error.

Comment: Also, it's as if, if the variable doesn't have a value `exist` doesn't find it and gives me a 0.

Comment: Um... that's what EXIST is for - telling you if a variable exists.